# How can we still ignore degenerate terms after changing basis in perturbation theory, isn't the denominator still zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory

I understand that for degenerate eigenfunctions of a Hamiltonian, one cannot use the non-degenerate [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)) to find the first order changes to the eigenfunctions since it includes terms of the form: $$ \frac{\langle m|V|n\rangle}{E_n - E_m} $$ which for: $$E_n=E_m$$ has a denominator of zero, so we change the basis in this degenerate case so that: $$\langle m|V|n\rangle =0$$ However, now the situation is $0/0$ which is undefined so how can we assume it is equal to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there are in fact first order perturbations to the energy eigenfunctions that involve other eigenfunctions in the degenerate subspace, it's just that in order to derive these perturbations you need to use the $O(\lambda^2)$ equation rather than the $O(\lambda)$ equation (the terms end up being $\propto \frac{\lambda^2}{\lambda} = \lambda$ so still a first order perturbation).

The derivation is presented here: [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch1.pdf). It shows that the formula will vary depending on whether the eigenstate is still degenerate after the first order perturbation or second order perturbation (and so on...) etc, but assuming the degeneracy is completely lifted after first order the formula is the following:

[image]

where the first summation is the usual result (summing over all terms outside the degenerate subspace) whereas the second summation is summing over the degenerate subspace.

My theory is often this term is excluded since it requires the computational effort of the $O(\lambda^2)$ equation to derive (and thus is a more complicated term), eventhough technically it is of size of first order and should be included.

Comment: Interesting, good find! So the numerator $\delta H_{n\ell,p}\delta H_{p,nk}$ is order $\lambda^2$ but the denominator in front, $E_{n,k}^{(1)} - E_{n,\ell}^{(1)}$ is $\lambda^1$, is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly so its of first order size! My new query is why this term is rarely mentioned, maybe it's just because it requires more computational effort since it uses the $O(\lambda^2)$ equation so for a 'very rough approximation' people ignore it, or maybe since the dimension of the degenerate subspace is usually much lower than the total space that means you can still get like 99% of 'the way there' to the first order perturbation of the eigenfunction without considering this sum? I'm not sure if that argument is valid though.

Comment: I'm guessing one reason is that most of the time we are not really interested in the state itself, but rather expectation values of observables. So we perform the process similar to finding the first order correction to the energy, where the "usual" expressions from non-degenerate PT are indeed correct to first and second order.

Comment: Yes, that's my impression at least.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate, let there be two eigenstates of $H_0$ called $|a \rangle$, $|b \rangle$ with the same (lowest) energy $E_0$. As you say, if we tried to compute

\begin{equation} \frac{\langle n|V|m \rangle}{E_0 - E_0}, \quad n,m \in a,b \end{equation}

then we would most likely get into trouble. But what we *can* do is to diagonalize $V$ in the subspace spanned by $|a \rangle$, $|b \rangle$. Of course, this is an approximation, because $V|a\rangle$ almost certainly has components outside of the subspace spanned by $|a \rangle$, $|b \rangle$. Even so, we can compute the eigenvectors of the matrix with elements

\begin{equation} W_{n,m} = \langle n|V|m \rangle, \quad n,m \in a,b \end{equation}
Unless we are very unlucky, the (two, in this case) eigenvectors $|\alpha \rangle$, $|\beta \rangle$ will *not* have the same eigenvalues. This is what is meant when we say that the perturbation "lifts" the degeneracy.

The change of basis you mention refers to the change to this $|\alpha \rangle$, $|\beta \rangle$ basis, and since these two states have different energies $V_{\alpha}$ and $V_{\beta}$, we will not be dividing by 0 anymore. Let's see this.

The perturbation expansion equation to first order is [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#First_order_corrections)

\begin{equation} (H_0 + \lambda V) \left( |n^{(0)}\rangle + \lambda |n^{(1)}\rangle \right) = \left(E_n^{(0)} + \lambda E_n^{(1)} \right) \left( |n^{(0)}\rangle + \lambda |n^{(1)}\rangle \right) \end{equation}

Expanding and taking terms that are first order in $\lambda$ gives

\begin{equation} H_0 |n^{(1)}\rangle + V|n^{(0)}\rangle = E_n^{(0)}|n^{(1)}\rangle + E_n^{(1)}  |n^{(0)}\rangle  \end{equation}

Reorganizing for $|n^{(1)} \rangle$ and changing sign:

\begin{equation} \left(E_n^{(0)} - H_0 \right) |n^{(1)}\rangle  =   V|n^{(0)}\rangle - E_n^{(1)}  |n^{(0)}\rangle \tag{1} \label{1} \end{equation}

With the results form above, the basis for our whole Hilbert space is now
\begin{equation} \left\{|\alpha \rangle, |\beta \rangle, |k_2 \rangle, |k_3 \rangle, \ldots \right\} \end{equation}
where for simplicity we assume that the $|k_i \rangle$ have distinct eigenvalues $E_i$. Eq. \eqref{1} applies to any of these; in particular it applies to $|n^{(0)} \rangle = |\alpha \rangle$. In that case, $E_n^{(1)}$, the first order correction to $E_0$ for $| \alpha \rangle$, is simply $\langle \alpha| V | \alpha \rangle = V_{\alpha}$.

In order to find the first order correction to $|\alpha \rangle$, namely $|\alpha^1 \rangle$, we can insert the resolution of the identity in front of the $V$-term in \eqref{1}:

\begin{equation} \left(E_0 - H_0 \right) |\alpha^{(1)}\rangle  =   \left( |\alpha \rangle \langle \alpha | + |\beta \rangle \langle \beta | + \sum_{i=2,3,\ldots} |k_i \rangle \langle k_i| \right) V|\alpha \rangle -  V_{\alpha}  |\alpha \rangle  \end{equation}

**Here comes the crucial part:** since $|\alpha \rangle$ and $|\beta \rangle$ have different "eigenvalues" of $V$, they belong to orthogonal subspaces, hence $\langle \beta |V| \alpha \rangle = 0$. Hence

\begin{equation} \left(E_0 - H_0 \right) |\alpha^{(1)}\rangle  =   \left(  \sum_{i=2,3,\ldots} |k_i \rangle \langle k_i| \right) V|\alpha \rangle + V_{\alpha} |\alpha \rangle + \langle \beta |V|\alpha \rangle |\beta \rangle - V_{\alpha}  |\alpha \rangle  \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \left(E_0 - H_0 \right) |\alpha^{(1)}\rangle  =   \left(  \sum_{i=2,3,\ldots} |k_i \rangle \langle k_i| \right) V|\alpha \rangle  \end{equation}

Notice that *both the $\alpha$ **and** the $\beta$ parts* are gone from the RHS! This means that the rest of the derivation, which involves dotting with $\langle k_i|$ on both sides (see the link), is exactly like the steps for the non-degenerate case. We never divide by 0.

Comment: But I thought that now we have two vectors |c> and |d> of $E_0$ that satisfy <c|V|d>=0, in order to calculate the first order change to |c> by the perturbation, you sum over all values of $ \frac{<n|V|c>}{E_n - E_0}$ using the $\it{unperturbed}$ energies in the denominator, so what I was referring to in my question is that if you let this sum include  $ \frac{<d|V|c>}{E_0 - E_0}$ you will get a 0/0 term. However most resources take this sum for $E_n \neq E_0$ and so exclude this term, which I'm not sure why we're allowed to do since 0/0 is undefined and not 0.

Comment: Please see my edited and extended answer.

Comment: I feel like I'm closer to understanding, but I'm not quite there. How can you use what you've written to prove that $<\beta|\alpha^{(1)}>=0$? Won't you just get $0 \times<\beta|\alpha^{(1)}>=0$ so 0=0 on both sides so $<\beta|\alpha^{(1)}>$ can equal anything, much like 0/0?

Comment: No, the whole point is that the contribution to $|\alpha^{(1)} \rangle$ from $|\psi \rangle$ is proportional to $\langle \psi | V | \alpha^{(0)} \rangle$. For $|\psi \rangle = |\beta \rangle$ this contribution is zero. Another way of saying the same thing is that we already took care of this contribution when we diagonalized $V$ in the subspace, to find $|\alpha \rangle$. We conclude this _before_ we need to divide on both sides by anything.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to disagree, in [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch1.pdf) on page 19 onwards, it shows that we can only obtain the piece of $|\alpha^{(1)}>$ outside the degenerate subspace by using the above $O(\lambda)$ equation. We obtain no new information (0=0) for the parts inside the degenerate subspace (here the coefficient of $|\beta>$) and must instead use the $O(\lambda^2)$ to obatin this part.